# Android USB Debugging has stopped working

Tags: android, device, usb-debugging

This problem started just two days ago.

Suddenly USB Debugging for Android is not working on my system.

My Current status..

Emulators are being properly detected and work 1000%
But when i plug in a device it shows up under devices but a connection is not established by adb.

Running 'devices '  command from adb does not list it as one of the attached devices.
I have tried with 3 diff devices HTC One , Galaxy Advance , Galaxy POP it all the same situation.

System Config

Windows 7 64 bit
Eclipse 4.2.2
ADT Plugin 22.3.0
Platform-tools  19.0.1

I think the last modifications i did to the system is updating the Android Sdk using SDK Manager.
I am not sure what all got updated.

What i tried so far..

Restarting Eclise / System..
Reinstalling the ADT Plugin.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this problem.

Comment: Drivers might be missing after system update, can you check them?

Comment: try rebooting the device

Comment: Also try a different USB cable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work but still not sure what the problem was.

Here is what i did ...

I Downloaded the latest ADT Bundle,
then pointed the SDK to my original set i  was using before as it contained the full set of platforms ,docs etc.

For any one who needs to do this ..

1. Open the Eclipse in the downloaded bundle.  (It contains the latest
   platform only)
2. Goto Window -> Preferences
3. Choose Android on the Left side
4. On the Right Click Browse and select the "android-sdk" folder that
   you need to use
5. Click OK at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue, I couldn't even re-install the drivers. A restart of the computer ended up fixing the issue.

Comment: I had to try this several times .. going to Developer Options on the device and turning off then back on the USB Debugging. I gave up last night after several tries, but then this morning with reboot .. all worked well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If none of the answers above helped you (as was my case), try this dumb solution, which worked for me:

I have 3 USB ports on my laptop. Only one of them works with debugging. Thus, try different ports on your device, if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe due to the emulators blocking the access to the adb drivers...
Try this,
* Power off emulator
* In command window type
'adb kill-server' then
'adb start-server' then
'adb devices'

This may solve it...

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to locate the **android_winusb** path of **Google USB driver** through control panel. Update driver software->let me pick list of device drivers->"C:\android-sdks\extras\google\usb_driver"->next and finish.
2. Make sure that you have **enabled** the **USB Debugging mode**

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue and I discovered Eclipse was not detecting my Android phone, connected via USB, because I had the phone connected as Camera (PTP). When I set it to Media device (MTP), Eclipse was able to detect my phone and launch to it.

You can change this mode in newer version of Android via the pull down tray (top).

Hope that helps anyone who had the same issue as me.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A few things that I try when this (regularly) happens:

- Check cable is properly seated
- Restart phone
- On phone, Settings > More > Developer options, disable then re-enable USB debugging
- On PC, open command prompt and type 'adb devices'; if phone appears but status is 'unauthorized' you need to respond to a prompt on the phone.

Keep looking out for a USB symbol in the top left corner of the phone, this usually means adb is connected.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is flipping the USB C cable upside down (where it connects to the phone). Other solutions like restarting the phone or using another USB port on the computer didn't work. Quite unbelievable - if I flip the cable it stops working, flip it back and everything's fine. This is an official Samsung cable by the way.